# How to return address types from google maps geocode?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I am currently using the google maps api to geocode locations on the map and return the address of the street.

I currently return the address with the following code:

```
        function codeLatLng(markerPos) {
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': markerPos}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                //Set markerAddress variable
                var markerAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
alert(markerAddress);
...
```

But what if I don't want to return the formatted address but a more detailed version using Address Component Types, how can I return certain address values like: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I ask, why are you checking for `results[1]` and then using `results[0]` (or is it just a typo I should ignore)?

As long as `status` is `OK`, there will be *at least* one result.
Otherwise, `status` would be `ZERO_RESULTS`.

Anyway, you can use something like this:

```
function codeLatLng(markerPos) {
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': markerPos}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var markerAddress = results[0].address_components[0].long_name
          + ' (type: ' + results[0].address_components[0].types[0] + ')';
      alert(markerAddress);
```

You can play a lot with the whole `address_components` array, have fun! :)

For even more fun, have a look at the (source code of the) Google Maps API v3 Geocoder Tool at http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html

Answer (score 1):

`long_name` is the full text description or name of the address component as returned by the Geocoder.

```
 function codeLatLng(markerPos) {
                geocoder.geocode({'latLng': markerPos}, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {
                    //Set markerAddress variable
                    var markerAddress = results[0].long_name;
    alert(markerAddress);
...
```

Comment: hmm... that alerts as 'undefined' any other ideas