# Extracting Address Types from Google Geocdoe

Tags: jquery, json, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

Goal: Trying to geocode an address inputted by a user, and then take the info, place it into a form and input this info into a database.

The road so far: I have somewhat successfully accomplished this task with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
        //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
        source : function(request, response) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address' : request.term
            }, function(results, status) {
                response($.map(results, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label : item.formatted_address,
                        value : item.formatted_address,
                        latitude : item.geometry.location.lat(),
                        longitude : item.geometry.location.lng(),
                        streetNo : item.address_components[0].long_name,
                        streetName : item.address_components[1].long_name,
                        town : item.address_components[2].long_name,
                        province : item.address_components[4].long_name,
                        postal : item.address_components[6].long_name,
                        country : item.address_components[5].long_name
                    }

                }));
            })
        },
        //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
        select : function(event, ui) {

            //Now that an address has been selected, show the address form
            $("#newReview").show('fast');
            $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
            $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
            $("#streetNo").val(ui.item.streetNo);
            $("#streetName").val(ui.item.streetName);
            $("#streetNo").val(ui.item.streetNo);
            $("#town").val(ui.item.town);
            $("#postal").val(ui.item.postal);
            $("#province").val(ui.item.province);
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
            marker.setPosition(location);
            map.setCenter(location);

            $(".correctAddress").click(function() {
                if($(".correctAddress").val() == "yes") {
                    $("#map").hide('fast');
                };
            });

            $(".inCorrectAddress").click(function() {
                if($(".inCorrectAddress").val() == "no") {
                    $("#map").show('fast');
                };
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**NOTE** I have only included the code that does the "work".

**What it does right now:**: A user can look for an address, they get an autocomplete suggestion, when they select an address, a "form" with some fields appears, with the address information already populated.

The issue however, is that depending on what address ends up being selected, the information may not always match up.

I.E. 1139 Ontario Rd, Welland ON, L3B 5E5, Canada will work fine, and the fields will populate correctly, but if the user selects a "place" or an incorrect address like:

Cornelia Ct, 81 Cornelia St W, Smiths Falls ON etc....

Then the info is no good because instead of a street number, which should be 81, I get the name "Cornelia Ct" because in this instance:

```
streetNo : item.address_components[0].long_name,
```

That array node is actually the "Cornelia Ct" name, which is the first part of the address.

What I need to be able to do is extract the "types" given back by the geocode, as in this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON 
or the info on this link: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

That way, if I can do that the street number will always be "street_number" and street name "route" etc.. etc..., allowing me to keep my data valid and uniform.

I've checked out this question on stackoverflow:

[How to return address types from google maps geocode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942108/how-to-return-address-types-from-google-maps-geocode) and that answer works, but it's doing the same thing I am already.

I admittedly have little experience parsing JSON but with what I understand and have tried so far, I think there would be a way to use the actual "types" name instead of the array's node number?

I have tried various things like:

```
item.address_components['street_name'].long_name
```

and variations of it but I can't seem to crack it.

The second issue with this code is that by asking for those specific results, the auto complete search only gives you a suggestion when you have most of it typed in already, as if it's waiting to match all those fields before it guesses.

If I could use the array outside of the "return" from geocoding theoretically it should then allow for a more fluid search, as it does if I remove:

```
streetNo : item.address_components[0].long_name,
streetName : item.address_components[1].long_name,
town : item.address_components[2].long_name,
province : item.address_components[4].long_name,
postal : item.address_components[6].long_name,
```

Thanks in advance for your time folks!

Comment: Is my question in the wrong place maybe? I've made no progress so far on my own, It's likely right in my face but I can't pinpoint it so far.

Comment: There is so much information in your question and it goes in so many different directions, it's hard to figure out exactly what you are asking. What is the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Instead of referencing the array by it's number, ie item.address_components[4].long_name. I need to reference the array by it's "type", 

i.e.: item.address_components['street_name'].long_name

using 'street_name' instead of '2', every time I try though, the code won't run.

The reason I need the type instead of the number is that the addresses don't all come back in uniform structure, depending on what the user selects.

I.E. sometimes it's just a town and state, sometimes a whole, 5 part address (street number, street name etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I've just got this working myself, here's my solution. I used [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) on the input as it can be hidden/shown in my code, but this line can be edited to remove the plugin if you wish.

```
$("#GeneralLocation").livequery(function() {
  $(this).autocomplete({
    //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
    source: function(request, response) {
      geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
        response($.map(results, function(item) {
          return {
            label:  item.formatted_address,
            value: item.formatted_address,
            address_components: item.address_components,
            latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
            longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
          }
        }));
      })
    },
    minLength: 3,  //only start suggestions after this many chars
    //Executed upon selection of an address
    select: function(event, ui) {

  // Inline function, Return an address field by type
  function getaddrfield(addr,type) {
    var ret = "";
    $.each(addr,function(index, c) {
      if ($.inArray(type,c.types)>=0)
        ret = c.long_name;
    });
    return(ret);
  }

      loc_suburb = getaddrfield(ui.item.address_components, "locality");
      loc_state = getaddrfield(ui.item.address_components, "administrative_area_level_1");
      loc_country = getaddrfield(ui.item.address_components, "country");
    }
});
```

Tips are most welcome, but I hope that helps someone.

Don
have a great day